# How to find the file defining a fish function?

Tags: fish

Fiddling with `fish_vi_key_bindings`, I would love to know where this function is defined. My intuition is that functions exist defined in files outside of `~/.config/fish/functions`, but I can't see them.

How can I know see where that function is defined? Something like

```
function funcfile the-func -d 'show the file for a function'
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since fish 2.6.0, the `functions` builtin has a "--details" option that can show this: `functions --details fish_vi_key_bindings`.

Before that, you can just search `$fish_function_path` for the first match. E.g. with GNU grep:

```
grep --files-with-matches "function fish_vi_key_bindings" $fish_function_path/*.fish
```

---

> My intuition is that functions exist defined in files outside of ~/.config/fish/functions, but I can't see them.

Your idea is correct. What you are probably thinking about is $fish_function_path. That's a list with directories that fish searches for functions, stopping at the first match.

Comment: Also, starting with the same release the `type` command gives that info: `$ type fish_vi_key_bindings | head`: `fish_vi_key_bindings is a function with definition
     # Defined in /usr/local/share/fish/functions/fish_vi_key_bindings.fish @ line 1
     function fish_vi_key_bindings --description 'vi-like key bindings for fish'
     if contains -- -h $argv`